# Rename multiple dataframe columns using purrr

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have the following list of data frames containing a column named `cyl`

```
# Create 3 dataframes with identical column names
mt_list <- list(head(mtcars[, 1:2]), tail(mtcars[, 1:2]), mtcars[13:18, 1:2])
mt_list
#> [[1]]
#>                    mpg cyl
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8
#> Valiant           18.1   6
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>                 mpg cyl
#> Porsche 914-2  26.0   4
#> Lotus Europa   30.4   4
#> Ford Pantera L 15.8   8
#> Ferrari Dino   19.7   6
#> Maserati Bora  15.0   8
#> Volvo 142E     21.4   4
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>                      mpg cyl
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8
#> Fiat 128            32.4   4

# New 'cyl' column names to change to (they are a character vector)
new_cyl_names <- c("cyl1", "cyl2", "cyl3")
new_cyl_names
#> [1] "cyl1" "cyl2" "cyl3"
```

I would like to name `cyl` to be the corresponding value in the character vector `new_cyl_names`.

I tried to do this as follows:

```
# Custom function to change cyl to the 
# character value contained in new_colname
change_colname_cyl <- function(df, new_colname){
    df %>% 
        dplyr::rename(new_colname = cyl)
}

# The following should change the names to cyl1, cyl2, cyl3
purrr::map2(.x = mt_list, .y = new_cyl_names, ~ change_colname_cyl(.x, .y))
```

This results in (first data frame shown only):

```
[[1]]
                   mpg new_colname
Mazda RX4         21.0           6
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0           6
Datsun 710        22.8           4
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4           6
Hornet Sportabout 18.7           8
Valiant           18.1           6
```

Could anyone please help me use `purrr` correctly for this i.e. change `cyl` to `cyl1` in this case instead of `new_colname` per above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made a slight modification of your function. I think now it works. See this (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) to learn more about standard evaluation and non-standard evaluation in `dplyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# List of data frames
mt_list <- list(head(mtcars[, 1:2]), tail(mtcars[, 1:2]), mtcars[13:18, 1:2])

# New column names
new_cyl_names <- c("cyl1", "cyl2", "cyl3")

# Create the function
change_colname_cyl <- function(df, new_colname){
  df %>% rename(!!new_colname := cyl)
}

# Apply the function
map2(mt_list, new_cyl_names, ~ change_colname_cyl(.x, .y))
[[1]]
                   mpg cyl1
Mazda RX4         21.0    6
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0    6
Datsun 710        22.8    4
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4    6
Hornet Sportabout 18.7    8
Valiant           18.1    6

[[2]]
                mpg cyl2
Porsche 914-2  26.0    4
Lotus Europa   30.4    4
Ford Pantera L 15.8    8
Ferrari Dino   19.7    6
Maserati Bora  15.0    8
Volvo 142E     21.4    4

[[3]]
                     mpg cyl3
Merc 450SL          17.3    8
Merc 450SLC         15.2    8
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4    8
Lincoln Continental 10.4    8
Chrysler Imperial   14.7    8
Fiat 128            32.4    4
```

#### Update

Based on Paul's comments. The following seems to be a more direct and concise way to rename the column.

```
map2(mt_list, new_cyl_names, ~rename(.x, !!.y := cyl))
```

Comment: Is `quo_name` needed? It looks like `map2(mt_list, new_cyl_names, ~rename(.x, !!.y := cyl))` does the same thing.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for your comment. It is true that `quo_name` is not needed in this case. I have updated my post based on your suggestion.

Comment: @ycw. Thanks for the response - though when I run your code it gives a `Error: All arguments to rename() must be named.`. Does it give a similar error for you? Also minor point the `ibrary(tidyverse)` should be changed to `library(tidyverse)`. Also @Paul 's concise solution produces the same error for me

Comment: @user4687531 Thanks for pointing out the typo. I have fixed that. No, I did not have this error. Please make sure you used the latest version of `tidyverse`.

Comment: Thanks @ycw. I just updated the `tidyverse`. My `sessionInfo()` shows the following ```other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0     purrr_0.2.2     readr_1.1.0     tidyr_0.6.1    
[5] tibble_1.3.3    ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.1.1```. Does that agree with yours? I am still getting the same error (for both `map2` functions)

Comment: Ah, I had to manually update `dplyr` by itself. For some reason doing `install.packages("tidyverse")` and `update.packages("tidyverse")` and `library(tidyverse)` and restarting R did not update `dplyr`. Did I update `dplyr` incorrectly above? BTW - I am accepting your solution :)

Answer (score 4):

We could use the `setnames` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
map2(mt_list, new_cyl_names, ~setnames(.x, 'cyl', .y))
mt_list
#[[1]]
#                   mpg cyl1
#Mazda RX4         21.0    6
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0    6
#Datsun 710        22.8    4
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4    6
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7    8
#Valiant           18.1    6

#[[2]]
#                mpg cyl2
#Porsche 914-2  26.0    4
#Lotus Europa   30.4    4
#Ford Pantera L 15.8    8
#Ferrari Dino   19.7    6
#Maserati Bora  15.0    8
#Volvo 142E     21.4    4

#[[3]]
#                     mpg cyl3
#Merc 450SL          17.3    8
#Merc 450SLC         15.2    8
#Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4    8
#Lincoln Continental 10.4    8
#Chrysler Imperial   14.7    8
#Fiat 128            32.4    4
```