# How do I rename the columns of all files in a data frame list?

Tags: dplyr, multiple-columns, rename, purrr

I have created a data frame list that contains 19 files from a single directory, as follows:

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx') #Loads all data in a folder
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel) #Creates a data file list
```

I am now trying to rename the columns in all of those files. How is the best way I can do this? I have tried to use the dplyr rename function, but this only works with a single file...

> Error in UseMethod("rename") :
> no applicable method for 'rename' applied to an object of class "list"

Thank you!

Comment: If your aim is to ```bind_rows``` these multiple dataframes together and the column names are consistent, then you could ignore them; accept the default names; bind the dataframes; then add the new names only once: ```df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel, col_names=FALSE, skip=1)```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616591/rename-multiple-dataframe-columns-using-purrr